# Neural networks very bad accuracy when using more than one hidden layer

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation

I have created the following neural network:

```
def init_weights(m, n=1):
    """
    initialize a matrix/vector of weights with xavier initialization
    :param m: out dim
    :param n: in dim
    :return: matrix/vector of random weights
    """
    limit = (6 / (n * m)) ** 0.5
    weights = np.random.uniform(-limit, limit, size=(m, n))
    if n == 1:
        weights = weights.reshape((-1,))
    return weights


def softmax(v):
    exp = np.exp(v)
    return exp / np.tile(exp.sum(1), (v.shape[1], 1)).T


def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(x, 0)


def sign(x):
    return (x > 0).astype(int)


class Model:
    """
    A class for neural network model
    """

    def __init__(self, sizes, lr):
        self.lr = lr

        self.weights = []
        self.biases = []
        self.memory = []
        for i in range(len(sizes) - 1):
            self.weights.append(init_weights(sizes[i + 1], sizes[i]))
            self.biases.append(init_weights(sizes[i + 1]))

    def forward(self, X):
        self.memory = [X]
        X = np.dot(self.weights[0], X.T).T + self.biases[0]
        for W, b in zip(self.weights[1:], self.biases[1:]):
            X = relu(X)
            self.memory.append(X)
            X = np.dot(W, X.T).T + b
        return softmax(X)

    def backward(self, y, y_pred):
        #  calculate the errors for each layer
        y = np.eye(y_pred.shape[1])[y]
        errors = [y_pred - y]
        for i in range(len(self.weights) - 1, 0, -1):
            new_err = sign(self.memory[i]) * \
                      np.dot(errors[0], self.weights[i])
            errors.insert(0, new_err)
            
        # update weights
        for i in range(len(self.weights)):
            self.weights[i] -= self.lr *\
                np.dot(self.memory[i].T, errors[i]).T
            self.biases[i] -= self.lr * errors[i].sum(0)
```

The data has 10 classes. When using a single hidden layer the accuracy is almost 40%. when using 2 or 3 hidden layers, the accuracy is around 9-10% from the first epoch and remains that way. The accuracy on the train set is also in that range. Is there a problem with my implementation that could cause such a thing?

Comment: Deep nets usually take a lot more time to train and they are more vulnerable to gradient decay problems. Make sure your deltas are not exactly 0 or blow up to infinity. I'm not an expert, but I know there are a lot of techniques out there to combat that.

Comment: What loss function are you using? ```[y_pred - y]``` will not be convex.

Comment: What is your data? MNIST? I'm asking for reproducibility purposes

Comment: Increasing the number of hidden layers will definitely not reduce the *training accuracy* limit. Do you split your datasets into train and test and the accuracy you claim to be stuck at 9-10% is actually the *test accuracy*? If not, it is safe to assume your backprop code is flawed.

Comment: @Kevin This is the derivation of cross-entropy and softmax.

Comment: @itamarkanter I don't know where the dataset is from, My professor gave it to us without saying that.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan The test accuracy is 9-10, the train is only a bit higher, 13% top. I know that it probably means that I have a bug in the backdrop but I can't see where.

Comment: @TomerShinar Can you explain this: `range(len(self.weights) - 1, 0, -1)` ? This makes `i` go from `len(self.weights)` to `1`, not to `0`.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Yes, I want this loop to do `len(self.weights) - 1` iterations because the list already have the last error which is `y_pred - y`. I did it like that and not from `len(self.weights) - 2` to 0 because those are the weights that I need for the algorithm.

Comment: @TomerShinar So you believe that you don't need to use all weight values for the backpropagation? Highly unlikely. Have you read `http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/`? Go check that out if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You asked about the accuracy improvement of a machine learning model, which is a very broad and ambiguous problem in the era of ML, because it varies between various model types and data types

In your case the model is neural network that has several factors on which accuracy is dependent. You are trying to optimize the accuracy on the basis of activation functions, weights or number of hidden layers which is not the correct way. To increase the accuracy you have to consider other factors too e.g. your basic checklist can be following

- Increase Hidden Layers
- Change Activation Functions
- Experiment with initial weight initialization
- Normalize Training Data
- Scale Training Data
- Check for Class Biasness

Now you are trying to achieve state of the art accuracy on the basis of very few factors, I don't know about your dataset as you haven't shown the pre processing code, but I recommend that you double check the dataset may be by correctly normalizing the dataset you can increase accuracy, also check if your dataset can be scaled and the most important thing if one of the class sample in your dataset is overloaded or too big in count as compared to other samples then it will also lead to the poor accuracy matrix.

For more details check [this](https://d4datascience.wordpress.com/2016/09/29/fbf/) it contains the mathematical proof and explanation how these things affect your ML model accuracy

Comment: The question was if there is a problem with the implementation of the backpropagation that causes an increasing error when adding more layers. even though it's very helpful, that doesn't answer the question.